# Phone numer formatting to display in only phone number text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a user fill in a phone number using the following code. Everything works great except I have multiple text fields in the same view controller i.e. name, phone number, email. Using the current code it locks up and doesn't allow input from any other but the phone number field.

My question is how do I specify for the code only to apply to this UI text field?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)pilotPhone shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{





    NSString *newString = [_phoneField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray *components = [newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSString *decimalString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    NSUInteger length = decimalString.length;
    BOOL hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && [decimalString characterAtIndex:0] == '1';

    if (length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || (length > 11)) {
        _phoneField.text = decimalString;
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableString *formattedString = [NSMutableString string];

    if (hasLeadingOne) {
        [formattedString appendString:@"1 "];
        index += 1;
    }

    if (length - index > 3) {
        NSString *areaCode = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
        [formattedString appendFormat:@"(%@) ",areaCode];
        index += 3;
    }

    if (length - index > 3) {
        NSString *prefix = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
        [formattedString appendFormat:@"%@-",prefix];
        index += 3;
    }

    NSString *remainder = [decimalString substringFromIndex:index];
    [formattedString appendString:remainder];

    _phoneField.text = formattedString;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What actually do u want to implement?

Comment: do u need the result allow the numbers only in phone textfield na, if yes set the tag for phone textfield

Comment: I need the phone number text field to format the numbers, and leave the other text fields alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the above code only for phone number textfield,Just put all the code inside the if condition like below :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)pilotPhone shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     // here self.txtPhoneNumber is ur phone number textfield
     if(pilotPhone == self.txtPhoneNumber)
     {

NSString *newString = [_phoneField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
// all other code ---------
return NO;
     }

return YES;
}
```